# Trying to use jquery ajax but can't parse JSON?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I'm trying to load some data via jQuery.getJSON() but it does not work:

here is my JSON:

```
{didwork=true,userid=123}
```

or it is

```
{didwork=false,userid=0}
```

here is my Javascript:

```
$.ajax({
  data["username"] = "u"
  data["password"] = "p";
  url: https://www.myurl.com/json.php,
  dataType: 'json',
  data: data,
  success: function(json){
    //fill it into div
  }
});
```

Comment: If you're ever curious if your JSON is or is not right, I'd higly recommend using [JsonLint.com](http://jsonlint.com/).

Comment: That code is a syntax error; it cannot possibly work. You should *always* have your JavaScript console open.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

your json string is wrong. it has to be

```
{"didwork":true,"userid":123}
```

or

```
{"didwork":false,"userid":0}
```

never use `=` and always use `"`

Comment: Just so you're aware: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130623/adding-company-logos-to-tag-wikis

Answer (score 4):

Your javascript is wrong..

you need to move the `data` initialization outside the ajax call..
plus the url needs to be quoted.. (*between `'`*)

```
var data = {};
data["username"] = "u";
data["password"] = "p";
```

this could also be represented with

```
var data = {'username': 'u', 'password': 'p'};
```

and the call

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'https://www.myurl.com/json.php',
  dataType: 'json',
  data: data,
  success: function(json){
    //fill it into div
  }
});
```

---

Your json is wrong

should be `{"didwork":true,"userid":123}`

---

If the url is to a different site then the one making the call it will fail due to [same origin policy](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCwQFjAA&url=http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy&ei=jg6cT7bvDsHd8AOmnMmWDw&usg=AFQjCNHVFZYpkC1JSDNgda021fYJ8pRuDQ&sig2=tpbe3OlY8X6LEX26s64IkQ)